# Prevent Python from rounding down to zero here?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding, zero

I have the following array and function:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([24, 23,  4, 52, 34, 49, 59, 18, 19])

def normalize(a):
    amin, amax = min(a), max(a)
    for i, val in enumerate(a):
        a[i] = (val-amin) / (amax-amin)
    return a
```

I get the following result:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

How can I prevent Python from not revealing the decimals of the zeros?

Comment: Are you using `Python 2`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, I am using ```Python 3.8```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what happens is because `a.dtype` is integer, so everything is converted to integer when you update a single position with `a[i] =...`.

In general, you should avoid looping in `numpy`:

```
a = np.array([24, 23,  4, 52, 34, 49, 59, 18, 19])

def normalize(a):
    # np.min is vectorized. Python's `min` is not
    amin, amax = np.min(a), np.max(a)
    return (a-amin)/(amax-amin)

normalize(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

By only having integers, your initial np array uses int-types for its cells. If you throw in just a single `X.0` in your initial array it will use floats:

```
a = np.array([24.0, 23, 4, 52, 34, 49, 59, 18, 19])

>>> print(normalize(a))
[0.36363636 0.34545455 0.  0.87272727 0.54545455 0.81818182  1.  0.25454545 0.27272727]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start the function by converting your array to floats.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([24, 23,  4, 52, 34, 49, 59, 18, 19])

def normalize(a1):
    a2 = a1.astype(float)
    amin, amax = min(a2), max(a2)
    return (a2-amin) / (amax-amin)
    
print(normalize(a))
```

Output:

```
[0.36363636 0.34545455 0.         0.87272727 0.54545455 0.81818182
1.         0.25454545 0.27272727]
```